# Bootstrap Navbar icon not displaying

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new to React and Bootstrap. I'm using Bootstrap 5.1.

I'm trying to create a Navbar with my logo in it. No matter what I try, I can't get the image to display. Here is my Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Navbar() { 
    return (
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img alt="House" src="/img/logo.svg" width="30" height="30"/>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    )
 }

 export default Navbar
```

The path to the logo is here, '/react-app/src/img/logo.svg' and I've tried pathing it multiple different ways without success.

And here is what I see.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use import to load the path like this:

```
import houseImgPath from './img/logo2.png' // replace with your own path
```

and then use it in your img `src`

```
 <img alt="House" src={houseImgPath} width="30" height="30"/>
```

Comment: That worked! In all of my searching I never saw that I had to import the image first. Thank you!

Comment: To confirm the path should be relative to the component. Often people might have folder structure like `src/components/Navbar/Navbar.js` in which case path to image would be `../../img/logo2.png`

Answer (score 2):

You should keep your image somewhere inside the src as you are doing (contrary to other suggestions) and import it like a module. The only time you might use the public folder is (maybe) if you wanted to preload the image or use the image as an icon for the app.

```js
import React from 'react';
import img from './img/image.jpg'        // or '../path/relative/to/component/image.jpg'

function Navbar() { 
    return (
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img alt="House" src={img} width="30" height="30"/>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the image for example:

```
import imageName from './img/logo2.png';
        
<img alt="House" src={imageName} width="30" height="30"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to put images in public folder in order to get this path `img/logo2.png` try it please and let me know

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by public folder. The /img folder is within the application folder. Where are you suggesting I put it?

Comment: you should put the folder img in this path /public/img/logo2.png in order to get the logo showed